# How to get attributes of a JSX element using Python regular expressions?

Tags: python, jsx

I want to write a simple parser for JSX code. I'm doing it for static analysis, to enforce some policies in our company.

These are possibilities:

```
<Component firstAttribute={dynamicValue} />

<Component firstAttribute="stringValue" secondAttribute={integerValue} />

<Component
   firstAttribute={dynamicValue}
   secondAttribute="stringValue"
   thirdAttribute={numericValue}
   booleanAttribute
/>

<Component
    handlerAttribute={() => {
        // JS code here
    }}
/>

<Component
   jsonAttribute={{
      key: value,
      key2: value2,
   }}
/>
```

As you see, it's really a mess. And these are not the only possible code snippets.

For simple attributes, it's not a big deal. I can easily extract them using this regular expression:

```
<\w+(\s+[\w*]*=['\"\{][^'\"\}]+['\"\}])*
```

But it gets really complicated when JSX and JS are mixed or when developers use string interpolation to provide a dynamic value for an attribute.

It seems to me that I'm not on the right path and regular expression is not the correct tool here.

Am I on the right path? How should I deal with this complexity? How can I extract attributes of elements reliably?

Comment: You need a _parser_. Why not use tools already set up to do this, like ESLint, rather than trying to recreate it in Python?

Comment: "Am I on the right path?" No, regexps aren't the right tool for parsing. "How should I deal with this complexity?" By using an actual parser. "How can I extract attributes of elements reliably?" With a parser designed for parsing JSX.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I need to do it in Python. I'm not in the Node.js environment. This is part of a larger series of codebase that has more than 500 other checks all written in Python. I can't switch to Node.js for this one.

Answer (score 3):

You're not going to have a good, reliable time with regular expressions; you'll need a parser.

Happily, [`esprima`](https://pypi.org/project/esprima/) is a thing:

```
from pprint import pprint

import esprima

code = """
<Component
   firstAttribute={dynamicValue}
   secondAttribute="stringValue"
   thirdAttribute={numericValue}
   booleanAttribute
    handlerAttribute={() => {
        // JS code here
    }}
   jsonAttribute={{
      key: value,
      key2: value2,
   }}
/>
"""

pprint(esprima.parseScript(code, {"jsx": True}))
```

will print out the AST for the code, e.g.

```
{
    type: "Program",
    sourceType: "script",
    body: [
        {
            type: "ExpressionStatement",
            expression: {
                type: "JSXElement",
                openingElement: {
                    type: "JSXOpeningElement",
                    name: {
                        type: "JSXIdentifier",
                        name: "Component"
                    },
                    selfClosing: True,
                    attributes: [
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "firstAttribute"
                            },
                            value: {
                                type: "JSXExpressionContainer",
                                expression: {
                                    type: "Identifier",
                                    name: "dynamicValue"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "secondAttribute"
                            },
                            value: {
                                type: "Literal",
                                value: "stringValue",
                                raw: "\"stringValue\""
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "thirdAttribute"
                            },
                            value: {
                                type: "JSXExpressionContainer",
                                expression: {
                                    type: "Identifier",
                                    name: "numericValue"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "booleanAttribute"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "handlerAttribute"
                            },
                            value: {
                                type: "JSXExpressionContainer",
                                expression: {
                                    type: "ArrowFunctionExpression",
                                    generator: False,
                                    isAsync: False,
                                    params: [],
                                    body: {
                                        type: "BlockStatement",
                                        body: []
                                    },
                                    expression: False
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            type: "JSXAttribute",
                            name: {
                                type: "JSXIdentifier",
                                name: "jsonAttribute"
                            },
                            value: {
                                type: "JSXExpressionContainer",
                                expression: {
                                    type: "ObjectExpression",
                                    properties: [
                                        {
                                            type: "Property",
                                            key: {
                                                type: "Identifier",
                                                name: "key"
                                            },
                                            computed: False,
                                            value: {
                                                type: "Identifier",
                                                name: "value"
                                            },
                                            kind: "init",
                                            method: False,
                                            shorthand: False
                                        },
                                        {
                                            type: "Property",
                                            key: {
                                                type: "Identifier",
                                                name: "key2"
                                            },
                                            computed: False,
                                            value: {
                                                type: "Identifier",
                                                name: "value2"
                                            },
                                            kind: "init",
                                            method: False,
                                            shorthand: False
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                children: []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and from there it's just a matter of some tree traversal.