# Esprima for Python does not parse the JSX code

Tags: python, jsx

In [How to get attributes of a JSX element using Python regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76387687/how-to-get-attributes-of-a-jsx-element-using-python-regular-expressions) I was introduced to [esprima](https://pypi.org/project/esprima/) for Python.

I installed it and tried to use it. But it complains about the syntax.

These are my component's start lines:

```
import { Image } from 'Base'
import {
    AddCircle,
    ChevronRight,
} from 'Svg'

const Hero = ({
    firstFloatingImage,
    mobileBackgroundImage,
}) => {
    return <>
        <section class="relative bg-paydar-color2 bg-cover hero">

            <Image
                containerClass="sm:hidden absolute contain bottom-0 mx-auto"
                imageClass=""
                src={mobileBackgroundImage}
                alt="background image"
                priority
            />
```

And this is my Python code to test it:

```
import esprima

code = open('path_to_my_component.jsx').read().strip()
ast=esprima.parseScript(code)
print(ast)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
    return esprima.parseScript(code)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/esprima.py", line 100, in parseScript
    return parse(code, options, delegate, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/esprima.py", line 79, in parse
    ast = parser.parseModule() if isModule else parser.parseScript()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 2867, in parseScript
    body.append(self.parseStatementListItem())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1545, in parseStatementListItem
    self.tolerateUnexpectedToken(self.lookahead, Messages.IllegalImportDeclaration)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 240, in tolerateUnexpectedToken
    self.errorHandler.tolerate(self.unexpectedTokenError(token, message))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/error_handler.py", line 60, in tolerate
    raise error
esprima.error_handler.Error: Line 1: Unexpected token
```

I wanted to report this to their team, but [their GitHub](https://github.com/Kronuz/esprima-python) does not have the issues.

Does anybody know what might be wrong here?

**Update**

This is a test with another component:

```
const About = ({
    summary,
    title,
}) => {
    return <section>
        <div class="max-w-4xl mx-auto px-3 xl:px-0 pb-10 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="text-2xl sm:text-3xl md:text-4xl text-paydar-color31 my-6 md:my-10 text-center font-bold capitalize">
                {title}
            </div>
            <p class="leading-7 text-paydar-color3">
                {summary}
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}

export default About
```

And this is the error:

```
    return esprima.parseScript(code)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/esprima.py", line 100, in parseScript
    return parse(code, options, delegate, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/esprima.py", line 79, in parse
    ast = parser.parseModule() if isModule else parser.parseScript()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 2867, in parseScript
    body.append(self.parseStatementListItem())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1548, in parseStatementListItem
    statement = self.parseLexicalDeclaration(Params(inFor=False))
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1628, in parseLexicalDeclaration
    declarations = self.parseBindingList(kind, options)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1601, in parseBindingList
    lst = [self.parseLexicalBinding(kind, options)]
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1591, in parseLexicalBinding
    init = self.isolateCoverGrammar(self.parseAssignmentExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 503, in isolateCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1465, in parseAssignmentExpression
    body = self.parseFunctionSourceElements()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 2362, in parseFunctionSourceElements
    body.append(self.parseStatementListItem())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1556, in parseStatementListItem
    statement = self.parseStatement()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 2320, in parseStatement
    statement = self.parseReturnStatement()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 2094, in parseReturnStatement
    argument = self.parseExpression() if hasArgument else None
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1514, in parseExpression
    expr = self.isolateCoverGrammar(self.parseAssignmentExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 503, in isolateCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1430, in parseAssignmentExpression
    expr = self.parseConditionalExpression()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1338, in parseConditionalExpression
    expr = self.inheritCoverGrammar(self.parseBinaryExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 522, in inheritCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1280, in parseBinaryExpression
    expr = self.inheritCoverGrammar(self.parseExponentiationExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 522, in inheritCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1247, in parseExponentiationExpression
    expr = self.inheritCoverGrammar(self.parseUnaryExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 522, in inheritCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1240, in parseUnaryExpression
    expr = self.parseUpdateExpression()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1201, in parseUpdateExpression
    expr = self.inheritCoverGrammar(self.parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 522, in inheritCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 1096, in parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall
    expr = self.inheritCoverGrammar(self.parseNewExpression if self.matchKeyword('new') else self.parsePrimaryExpression)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 522, in inheritCoverGrammar
    result = parseFunction()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 597, in parsePrimaryExpression
    expr = self.throwUnexpectedToken(self.nextToken())
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/esprima/parser.py", line 237, in throwUnexpectedToken
    raise self.unexpectedTokenError(token, message)
esprima.error_handler.Error: Line 5: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: _Is_ the problem with JSX - the error points to line 1, which doesn't contain any. Can you cut it down to a [mre]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the JSX works just fine. It's part of a website and it works both in the development and in the production (after build). So I think there is no problem with JSX. How can I create a MRE for Python? Is there an online tool for it like CodeSandBox?

Comment: I'm not asking about whether the _JS_ works, you're reporting an error with the parsing of it _in Python_. Try parsing _less JS_ and see if it still throws.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, no it did not work with simpler component too. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing a module (that has `import`s and `export`s), use `esprima.parseModule(code, {"jsx": True})`.

Furthermore, Esprima does not support React's `<>` fragment syntax, so you'll have to hack those to their canonical form first (and yes, I'm aware it will happily replace that in e.g. strings within the source too, but can't be helped:

```
code = code.replace("<>", "<React.Fragment>")
code = code.replace("</>", "</React.Fragment>")
pprint(esprima.parseModule(code, {"jsx": True}))
```

prints out

```
{
    type: "Program",
    sourceType: "module",
    body: [
        {
            type: "ImportDeclaration",
            specifiers: [
                {
                    type: "ImportSpecifier",
                    local: {
                        type: "Identifier",
                        name: "Image"
                    },
                    imported: {
                        type: "Identifier",
                        name: "Image"
                    }
                }
            ],
            source: {
                type: "Literal",
                value: "Base",
                raw: "'Base'"
            }
        },
...
```

(once the missing tags were added ;-) )